# Resettable thread safe counter for application data in Java

Tags: multithreading, spring, web-applications, thread-safety, counter

Simple Requirement:
- Named counters that are reset to 0 on a daily, hourly or per minute basis. Next request to increment outside of limit would reset instead of incrementing. No need for a timer/alarm time resetting.
- API should be simple
- Thread Safe

A sample usage. Keep counter for a specific application/Business event to be used for logging or checking for limits.
Check if particular resource has been used more than its daily limit and stop access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Latest version posted on GitHub for anyone who is interested - https://github.com/mickyr/Awesome-Counter

My minimal implementation so far. Please critique if you find any issues/areas of improvements. Feedback, negative or positive welcomed. It will be a learning opportunity:

**Resettable Counter Class:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ResettableCounter {
    private String policyString;
    private AtomicInteger count;

    public ResettableCounter(String name, AtomicInteger counter) {
        this.policyString = name;
        this.count = counter;
    }

    public String getPolicyString() {
        return policyString;
    }

    public void setPolicyString(String policyString) {
        this.policyString = policyString;
    }

    public AtomicInteger getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

**CounterPolicy Enum**

```
public enum CounterPolicy{
    YEARLY("yyyy"),
    MONTHLY("yyyy/MM"),
    DAILY("yyyy/MM/dd"),
    HOURLY("yyyy/MM/dd hh"),
    PERMINUTE("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm");

    private String format;

    private CounterPolicy(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public String getFormat(){
        return this.format;
    }
}
```

**ResettableCounter Registry class:**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import CounterPolicy;
import ResettableCounter;

public class ResetableCounterRegistry {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, ResettableCounter> counterRegistry = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ResettableCounter>();
    private CounterPolicy policy = CounterPolicy.DAILY;

    public int incrementCount(String counterName){
        ResettableCounter counter = counterRegistry.get(counterName);       
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(policy.getFormat());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        if(counter==null)counterRegistry.putIfAbsent(counterName, new ResettableCounter(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()), new AtomicInteger()));
        counter=counterRegistry.get(counterName);
        if(!dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).equals(counter.getPolicyString())){
            int count = counter.getCount().get();
            if(counter.getCount().compareAndSet(count, 0))
                counter.setPolicyString(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
            else counter.getCount().incrementAndGet();
        }
        else counter.getCount().incrementAndGet();
        return counter.getCount().get();
    }

    public void setPolicy(CounterPolicy policy) {
        this.policy = policy;
    }   
}
```

As I said this is minimal implementation but hopefully can evoke a good conversation or help someone with a similar use case.